# Compiling and concat all sails.js API folder into JS to be run in browser without node app.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I've finish building rest API using sails.js. I would like to deploy this build to the server. However, I just feel that it doesn't make sense to be uploading the plain js files from the current directory to the server. Are there ways to compile all the js in API and config folder in a smaller package just like what webpack did for assets folder so that it will run on browser without running command node app.js

Is it normal to just copy the js files to server and run node app.js to start the application?

Comment: `Node.js` and Browser are different environments. When you are using Sails.js it is not plain Javascript underneath it is node.js. Hence, your code can **not** run in Browser.

Comment: @Sangharsh understand. meaning to say node app.js/sails lift is the only way to run this the API.

Comment: Yes, afaik. You should use `pm2`, `forever` or similar process manager to keep your process running after crashes.

Comment: @Sangharsh okay! got it! thank you!